# How to call asynchronous function conditionally in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, conditional-statements, ecmascript-5

I would like to make a conditional asynchronous function call in JavaScript/ES5.

Say I have a module `myService` with a function `myAsyncFunction`, which is doing some logic inside and returns result with a callback like the following:

```
myService.myAsyncFunction(param1, param2, (error, success) => {
    if (error) {
        // handle error
        return;
    }
    // handle success
});
```

But in certain conditions, I would like it to directly fall into the "handle success" without running the logic inside `myService.myAsyncFunction`, which may take some time and resources.

The most straightforward way that I imagine is to create a dummy function which imitates `myService.myAsyncFunction` and calls the callback with no error like the following:

```
var myGenericFunction;

if ( /* I would like to skip unnecessary logic */) {
    myGenericFunction = function (param1, param2, callback) {
        callback(null);
    }
} else {
    myGenericFunction = myService.myAsyncFunction;
}

myGenericFunction(param1, param2, (error, success) => {
    if (error) {
        // handle error
        return;
    }
    // handle success
});
```

This is what I have ended up with but I guess there should be a better way in terms of both syntax and performance. Do you have any suggestion for it?

Note: `Promise.resolve` on ES6 can propose a solution to directly fall into success case but I wonder what would be ES5 solution.

Comment: I don't understand, do you want to use Promises or not?  You have ~2 choices: use callbacks or use Promises (and maybe async/await).  Please pick one.  No matter what, if you choose an asynchronous approach, you have to be async the whole way down.

Comment: @zero298 No, I don't want to use Promise. I mentioned it since I would like you to know that I know 'Promise' way but prefer ES5 solution.

Comment: So, I removed 'Promise' from the title of the question in order not to cause confusion if that was the reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's super easy to pull in a `Promise` polyfill for javascript environments that don't support it. It should work all the way back to Ecmascript 3.

Ignoring that, if you have an async function such as this:

```
function myAsync(arg1, callback) {

}
```

But for some value or `arg1` you want to immediately call the callback, but you can't change the function, the reasonable way to do this, is indeed to just wrap it:

```
function myAsyncWrapped(arg1, callback) {
   if (arg1 === SOME_VALUES) {
     callback(null, true);
   } else {
     myAsync(arg1, callback);
   }
}
```

If you need to do this for *many* async functions, it could be generalized as:

```
function asyncWrapper(innerFunction) {
   return (arg1, callback) {
     if (arg1 === SOME_VALUES) {
       callback(null, true);
     } else {
       innerFunction(arg1, callback);
     }
   }
}
```

so you can call this as:

```
myAsyncWrapped = asyncWrapper(myAsync);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of alternate approaches to rolling your own Promise implementation.

You can use an existing one, such as Bluebird - http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html

You can also use a transpiler, such as Babel, which would allow you to write all of the next-gen ES that you wish and have it converted to ES5 pre-runtime - https://babeljs.io/docs/en

Comment: Thanks for suggestions @mattezell. I still look for non-Promise solution anyway.

Comment: No problemo. 

I think that there may be a bit of confusion introduced to the question by the statement 'So you can summarize the question as "How can I use Promise.resolve on ES5?" if a better/different method is not available.'. 

I think the assumption is "of course there's async because it's JavaScript" - and I think another widely held assumption is "using promises is cleaner/better than rolling your own alternative async implementation that behaves like promises".

Comment: Ok, I have also updated the note to remove "summary of question" stuff as the question is all on the title.